# Laravel join query with where conditions reads the compared value as a string rather than the field value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Trying to use a where statement that compares the value of 2 fields on laravel however laravel is treating "ticket_orders.status" in ('tickets.status','=','ticket_orders.status') as a string. but in works in the SQL query, can someone tell me what is wrong with my syntax?

```
$relevant_audit_tickets = TicketOrder::join('tickets','tickets.ticket_order_id','=','ticket_orders.id')->where('tickets.status','=','ticket_orders.status')->where('tickets.status','=','Created')->get();

SELECT * FROM ticket_orders tos inner join tickets t on t.ticket_order_id = tos.id where tos.status = t.status and tos.status = 'created';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare column by `whereRaw()` or by `whereColumn()`

```
->whereRaw('tickets.status = ticket_orders.status')
```

OR

```
->whereColumn('tickets.status', 'ticket_orders.status')
```

Query:

```
$relevant_audit_tickets = TicketOrder::join('tickets','tickets.ticket_order_id','=','ticket_orders.id')
->whereRaw('tickets.status = ticket_orders.status') //  OR ->whereColumn('tickets.status', 'ticket_orders.status')
->where('tickets.status','=','Created')
->get();
```